# Loop over an PostgreSQL array within a SELECT query, instead of within a PLPGSQL function

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a text[] ARRAY column within a PostgreSQL table and I need to run char_length() on each element inside the array within a SELECT query (normal SQL, not plpgsql) so that if any of the elements is more than 25 characters long, the SELECT returns 't' and 'f' otherwise. I know I can loop over the text[] within a custom plpgsql function but due to other reasons I need to find a way to do this in SQL directly.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of PostgreSQL 8.4, you can use the `UNNEST` function:

```
SELECT MAX((char_length(string) > 25)::INT)::BOOLEAN
FROM (
    SELECT my_array,UNNEST(my_array) AS string
    FROM my_table
) AS x
GROUP BY my_array;
```

Comment: Oh right, I thought that's what the OP wanted, but upon closer inspect, it's not... Answer updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`unnest`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) to break open the array and then some simple [`length`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) and [`exists`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html#AEN16644) stuff:

```
select exists(
    select 1
    from (
        select unnest(ar) as x
        from table_name
    ) as t
    where length(x) > 25
)
```

The `exists` and `select 1` business is just a convenient way to collapse result set to a single boolean (I'm sure there are other ways).